# Make nomenclature in {longtable} comply with {geometry}?

Tags: longtable, geometry, nomenclature

During the writing of my thesis, I found that the long lines within the Nomenclature, created by `longtable`, always exceed the length limit of `geometry` in the preamble. Could you suggest me how to solve this problem?
The following is the relevant code. Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}

\clearpage
\chapter*{Nomenclature}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\quad\; \textbf{\Large{Roman Letters}} \\
\begin{longtable}{p{50pt}p{400pt}}
$a$ & This is a long explanation of the symbol $a$ \\
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE is incomplete (it's missing `\usepackage{longtable}` and the `document` environment). Here's a minor modification that creates a complete document that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Nomenclature}

\begin{longtable}{p{50pt}p{400pt}}
\hline
$a$ & This is a long explanation of the symbol $a$ \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The `showframe` option is a useful debugging option that shows the page layout and I've added `\hline` to demonstrate the full width of the table, which shows the overfull problem:

[image: image of document]

The transcript (`.log`) file shows the page dimensions. The pertinent value is:

```
* \textwidth=421.10089pt
```

So the total text width is 421.10089pt. The `longtable` is started with:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{50pt}p{400pt}}
```

so the first column is 50pt and the second is 400pt and 50pt+400pt=450pt, which means it's already wider than the text width, but there's additionally the space between the columns, which in this case is 4 times the value of `\tabcolsep`. You can find this value by adding

```
\showthe\tabcolsep
```

before the `longtable`. This shows the value in the transcript:

```
> 6.0pt.
l.9 \showthe\tabcolsep
```

Therefore the total width of the table is 4 × 6pt + 450pt = 474pt. Since the text width is 421.10089pt this means that the table is 52.89911pt too wide, which LaTeX informs you in the transcript file:

```
Overfull \hbox (52.89911pt too wide) in alignment at lines 9--12
```

So you have to make one or both of your column widths smaller. For example:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{50pt}p{347pt}}
```

Alternatively, you could use a more automated method, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}
\usepackage[symbols,record,style=alttreegroup]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{roman}{Roman Letters}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{greek}{Greek Letters}

\glsxtrnewsymbol
 [group=roman,
  description={This is a long explanation of the symbol $a$}]
 {a}{$a$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol
 [group=roman,
  description={This is a long explanation of the symbol $b$}]
 {b}{$b$}

\glsxtrnewsymbol
 [group=greek,
  description={This is a long explanation of the symbol $\alpha$}]
 {alpha}{$\alpha$}
\glsxtrnewsymbol
 [group=greek,
  description={This is a long explanation of the symbol $\beta$
  with some filler text to make the explanation longer.}]
 {beta}{$\beta$}

% set up the width available for the symbol:
\setglossarypreamble[symbols]{\glssetwidest{MMMMM}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,title={Nomenclature}]
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Comment: @ Nicola Talbot many things to learn from you. Thank you.